# Python append single bit to bytearray

Tags: python, arrays, append

I have a bytearray containing some bytes, it currently look like this (Converted to ASCII):

> ['0b1100001', '0b1100010', '0b1100011', '0b10000000']

I need to add a number of 0 bits to this, is that possible or would I have to add full bytes? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Are you worried about using too much memory saving a full byte when all you need is a bit?

Comment: No, I just need to add a very specific number of 0's, and later I need to add 0's to the beginning of a bytearray.

Comment: A specific number of zeros?  Why not just store the number, like `1` or `3` instead of that many zeros?

Comment: The number is determined at runtime, 'specific' was probably a bad choice of words.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you need the bits added to? Each element of your list or an additional element that contains all 0's?

The former:
`myList[0] = myList[0] * 2 # ASL`

The later
`myList.append(0b000000)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a function at the moment , when you cant remember any default context of python.

```
>>> def naivebin(*a):
...     if isinstance(a[0],int):
...         return bin(a[0])[2:]
...     if isinstance(a[0],list):
...         return [bin(i)[2:] for i in a[0]]
... 
>>> naivebin(15)
'1111'
>>> naivebin([15,16,17])
['1111', '10000', '10001']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I defined a function just doing it with only 'str' and 'list' cause its just example.

```
>>> def padingbin(*a):
...     if isinstance(a[0],str):
...         return a[0]+a[1]
...     if isinstance(a[0],list):
...         print('What is args:' ,a)
...         print('What we generatd: ',[a[1] for x in range(len(a[0])) ],end='\n\n')

            #the val calls every element of list and i is your generated pad

...         return [a[0][val]+i for val in range(len(a)) for i in [a[1] for x in 
range(len(a[0])) ]]
... 

>>> padingbin(['0b10101','0b1101','0b10110'],'00')
What is args: (['0b10101', '0b1101', '0b10110'], '00')
What we generatd:  ['00', '00', '00']  #and combining this 3 pad with 3 element in list

['0b1010100', '0b1010100', '0b1010100', '0b110100', '0b110100', '0b110100']

>>> padingbin('0b1101','00')
'0b110100'
```

You mean this?I hope I helped.Thanks..